# Why does VirtualBox only have 32-bit option, no 64-bit option on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I have downloaded and installed the newest VirtualBox 6.1 for my Windows 10 (64-bit OS), but when I want to install 64-bit Linux, the New->Create Virtual Machine only displays a 32-bit option, no 64-bit option. Could anyone give any clues about this issue? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this happens do to one or more of these requirements not being met:

- You have an x64 CPU installed.
- Hardware virtualization is **enabled** in the BIOS.
- **For Intel:** VT-x (Intel Virtualization Technology) and VT-d are both **enabled**
- **For AMD:** AMD SVM (Secure Virtual Machine) is **enabled**
- Hyper-V (or similar technology) is **not enabled or installed**

If these don't help, see here for more details:
http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/